# Separar id en un array PHP

Tags: php

Recibo 3 ids juntos en una misma variable pero los quiero meter en un `array` para hacer un *random*, pero si meto la variable me coge la última.

CÓDIGO

```php
    $sql_encargados="SELECT * FROM far_clientes WHERE fcl_tipo=0;";
    $res_encargados = $bd->ejecutar($sql_encargados);
    while ($x=$bd->obtener_fila($res_encargados,0)){
      $var = $x['fcl_id'];
      $ran = array($var);
      $randomElement = $ran[array_rand($ran, 1)];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estás agregando valores a `$ran` sino que siempre la estás pisando.

Es decir, esta línea:

```
$ran = array($var);
```

Debería ser algo así:

```
$ran = array();
// ... código
$ran[] = $var;
// ... mas código
$randomElement = $ran[array_rand($ran, 1)];
```

Esto aplicado a tu código podría verse así:

```php
$sql_encargados="SELECT * FROM far_clientes WHERE fcl_tipo=0;";
$res_encargados = $bd->ejecutar($sql_encargados);
$ran = array(); // creamos el arrelgo
while ($x=$bd->obtener_fila($res_encargados,0)){
  
  $var = $x['fcl_id'];
  $ran[] = $var; // agregamos valores al arreglo
}
$randomElement = $ran[array_rand($ran, 1)]; // Obtenemos un valor random
```

---

Referencias:

- [PHP - arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Como ya han comentado, en cada bucle sobreescribes la variable ran.

Puedes usar array_push:

```
$sql_encargados="SELECT * FROM far_clientes WHERE fcl_tipo=0;";
$res_encargados = $bd->ejecutar($sql_encargados);
$ran = array(); //Crea el array
while ($x=$bd->obtener_fila($res_encargados,0)){
  $var = $x['fcl_id'];
  array_push($ran,$var); // Añade el valor al array
}
$randomElement = $ran[array_rand($ran, 1)];
```

Referencia: [array_push()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp)